# How does installing ubuntu alonside windows work?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, privacy

I am curious about is there any difference between installing just Ubuntu and installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Do they run separately or together?

As you know, Windows 10 is a privacy killer and if I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, is there any effect to privacy?

Comment: There's no difference. In a dual or multi-boot each OS runs independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As system itself Ubuntu is protective and does **not** talk to anyone about your private life, but other topic is your behavior in internet, there you have lot's to do by yourself.

As for installing it with Win 10, there is so many tutorials available, I will not try to beat them here briefly, googling found me [this](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-along-with-windows-10/) and [that](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) as first results and they seem pretty adequate. I just wanted to stress, that this is pretty straightforward process and Ubuntu gives you opportunity to shrink your Windows on disk, to make room for Ubuntu. Result is called dualboot system, where on boot you can choose, to which system you want to start this time.

And you can choose, which one starts by default. One observation from me: Win updates need a lot restarting, so if Ubuntu is default, Win can't finish it's updates without your interaction.

Comment: The example that you gave at the last, it was amazing. So the two systems run separately and independently,there is no effect with each other.Is that right?

Comment: @Atakan Yes, on booting you choose which system to load. Other system sits just on hard drive and waits it's time, those are just files, not loaded or executed any way. In Ubuntu you can easily access your Windows filesystem, other way around is possible, but not so simple.

Comment: That's a great explanation. So we assume I am hacked or there is a moving around virus or malware in my system when I use Ubuntu,will be hacked both systems or just the system that I use?

Comment: @Atakan If you have more questions, ask them as separate ones, please